# Wildfly taking a long time to start

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, wildfly

I have a project that is running on Wildfly 10.0 and uses Oracle SQL. I'm running Wildfly from Eclipse with project already added to it.

There seems to be an almost 4 minutes gap between binding OracleDS and starting project deployment:

Here's the snippet from the log:

```
13:22:21,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/OracleDS]
13:26:20,162 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "service-provider-example-depl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
```

Does this mean that binding datasource takes up 4 minutes? Or that starting my ploject deployment takes up that time? I suppose the latter, because the log message is "bound data source", not "binding data source".

What might be causing this? Everything worked fine till today, and I don't remember changing anything related to Wildfly, Java project or Oracle SQL.

**EDIT:** When I look at the task manager, I don't see anything taking up all of the resources(CPU, Memory or disk)

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.jboss.org/thread/275822.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything useful there, though. https://developer.jboss.org/thread/280575 has a bit more, but also a bit vague.